# TypeError: Books is not a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

This is my first time trying to make ruby on rails project and I struggle with the migrate command.

I followed this tutorial [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-migrations.htm).
When I try to use the migration: `rake db:migrate` I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
TypeError: Books is not a class
/home/dudi/tutorials/books/db/migrate/20150227191301_books.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
TypeError: Books is not a class
/home/dudi/tutorials/books/db/migrate/20150227191301_books.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

but the file says that Books is a class:

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     create_table :books do |t|
    t.column :title, :string, :limit => 32, :null => false
    t.column :price, :float
    t.column :subject_id, :integer
    t.column :description, :text
    t.column :created_at, :timestamp
     end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :books
  end
end
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

---

**EDIT:**

I tried to change the `class Book` to `class create_Book` and also the file name to `create_Book`. when I typed `rake db:migrate`, nothing happened (I guess it worked?), and on the web page I got this message:

```
Couldn't find Book with 'id'=all
```

on file `book_controller`:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController

 #printout of all the books in the database
 def list
   @books = Book.find(:all) 
 end
end
```

I also tried to change `Book.find` to `create_Book.find` I got this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `create_Book'
```

Comment: the name of your migration is the same as the name for the model - probably causing some confusion - try `class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: don't forget to rename the file to ```create_books.rb``` as well. also, remember that this could be done for you using generators. More info here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration

Answer (score 0):

First off, do you want Books to be able to store data in the database? Because you have a drop_table line in that migration. Which means you will create the table, and then delete it.

Secondly, **rake db:migrate is the last step**. Did you use the command 'rails generate model' during this tutorial? Or are you attempting to run the migration first? (note rails generate model will also generate a migration file for you automatically)

You will want to first create a model named Books, then you can run the migration. The error you received is looking for a Books class in your models, and cannot find one.

If you do already have a Books class in your model, please edit this to include that file. If we can see your actual Model instead of just the migration that will give us info as to why rails thinks there isn't a Books model there.

Your Books model should inherit from ActiveRecord::Base or inherit from another class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base. Is that the case?

Comment: hi, I have model folder with Book.rb file in it (as the tutorial says):

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :subject
   validates_presence_of :title
   validates_numericality_of :price, :message=>"Error Message"
end

Comment: Yeah what everyone else said above, you just need to rename the class to CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration

Comment: do I need to change the name only on the Migration? or also on the controller and models..?

Comment: Nope. You will want your model inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base, and the controller only deals with front end work, it has nothing to do with database migrations at all.  Change the class name to CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration . And then run rake db:migrate again and it should work just fine. Again though, you have a drop_table migration in there. So you are creating a table and then instantly deleting it. I would recommend removing that. Doesn't seem super useful.

Comment: The error you are getting now in your edit has to do with your controller, not with the rake db:migrate. You know how you can check? Look at schema.rb. If you see your columns there, youll know the database is set up properly and that the error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Jimi, I don't see the columns of the tables.. but now the controllers works fine, I can see the web page properly.